# Unable to set default entry in grub menu

Tags: grub

I have a computer with two different Debian operating systems installed on it. I usually use the first installed one, but I'm not able to correctly set up grub to use that as the default option: every time I turn on my computer, the second installation on Debian is selected.

1. I tried to set the option `GRUB_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` to 2 (as the first installed operating system is the third on the grub list). It did not work.
2. I tried to set `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` and `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true`. It did not work too.

EDIT: In both cases I run `sudo update-grub` after the editing.

I've run out of ideas and "duckduckgoing" for the problem does not help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run `sudo update-grub` to regenerate your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`?

Comment: Yes I did. I've just double-checked in order not to make mistakes, but I did it. I'm going to update my answer accordingly

Comment: Ok, repeat the steps on the other Debian installation. GRUB is probably using `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` of the other installation.

Comment: @Freddy Thanks a lot: that worked! If you post it as an answer I'd be glad to mark it as solved!

Comment: Please self-answer your question, I don't know what you changed in your grub config ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to fix this issue thanks to Freddy, who posted some comments under my question.

I simply edited the file `/etc/default/grub` of *the other Debian installation* by changing `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to `GRUB_DEFAULT=2` (the third row in my GRUB menu was the one I wanted as default) and run `sudo update-grub`. Then I rebooted and everything worked fine as expected. Thank you Freddy.